# VIM: How to paste in some begin lines

Tags: vim, macvim

I want to paste the same text at the start of some lines of my document all at once.

[For example]
-Before-

```
'1','North America'
'2','South America'
'3','Europe'
```

-After-

```
INSERT INTO 'continent' ('id' ,'name') VALUES ('1','North America'
INSERT INTO 'continent' ('id' ,'name') VALUES ('2','South America'
INSERT INTO 'continent' ('id' ,'name') VALUES ('3','Europe'
```

Please tell me if there is a way of doing this.
Thanks!

Comment: Deleted my answer, since the linked duplicate is an excellent illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the first character, <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> (switch to visual blockwise selection), `jj` (to move down two lines), `I` (capital i, switches to insert before block), and then <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> to instert contents of the default register. When you hit ESCAPE you will see that the text that you've inserted appears on all other lines.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:%s/^/INSERT INTO 'continent' ('id' ,'name') VALUES (/
```

`%` stands for the whole document. You can replace the `%` with range. For example

```
 :1,4s/^/INSERT INTO 'continent' ('id' ,'name') VALUES (/
```

will insert only at the begining of the first 4 lines.